# Generate XML from oracle11 DB

Tags: xml, oracle

I need to generate xml format given below from an oracle 11 database. All tag names are static strings. Data for nodes D1, D2, D3 etc I am able to get in a single query using a 2 table join.

If I use XMLElement("Node1", XMLElement("Node2",XMLElement("Node3",XMLElement("D1", .....
then even Node1, Node2 is getting returned with each row of data. I need Node1 and Node2 only once open at top and close at bottom. Any idea how can I do that?

```
<Node1>
   <Node2 key = "XYZ">
        <Node3>
            <D1> R1F1 </D1>
            <D2> R1F2 </D2>
            <D3> R1F3 </D3>
        </Node3>
        <Node3>
            <D1> R2F1 </D1>
            <D2> R2F2 </D2>
            <D3> R2F3 </D3>
        </Node3>
        <Node3>
        <D1> R3F1 </D1>
        <D2> R3F2 </D2>
        <D3> R3F3 </D3>
        </Node3>
   </Node2>
</Node1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
WITH
Dat (c1, c2, c3) AS (
  SELECT 'R1F1', 'R1F2', 'R1F3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'R2F1', 'R2F2', 'R2F3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'R3F1', 'R3F2', 'R3F3' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
  XMLSerialize(CONTENT XMLElement("Node1", XMLElement("Node2", XMLAttributes ('XYZ' AS "key"),(SELECT XMLAgg(XMLElement("Node3", XMLElement("D1", c1), XMLElement("D2", c2), XMLElement("D3", c3))) FROM Dat)))) doc FROM DUAL
;
```

Returned on Oracle 11.2: `<Node1><Node2 key="XYZ"><Node3><D1>R1F1</D1><D2>R1F2</D2><D3>R1F3</D3></Node3><Node3><D1>R2F1</D1><D2>R2F2</D2><D3>R2F3</D3></Node3><Node3><D1>R3F1</D1><D2>R3F2</D2><D3>R3F3</D3></Node3></Node2></Node1>`